# Connection to http://xxxxx.com refused

Tags: ssl, soapui

I am using SoapUI to test the third party web service(asmx). The testing service is SSL required, generally in most production cases the service is used over http, for the test goal the third party asks us to use SSL.

So I added the https uri to the SoapUI and invoked it.

However I got the error:

```
ERROR:org.apache.http.conn.HttpHostConnectException: Connection to http://xxxxx.com refused
at com.eviware.soapui.impl.wsdl.support.http.SoapUIMultiThreadedHttpConnectionManager$SoapUIClientConnectionOperator.openConnection(SoapUIMultiThreadedHttpConnectionManager.java:279)
at org.apache.http.impl.conn.AbstractPoolEntry.open(AbstractPoolEntry.java:149)
at org.apache.http.impl.conn.AbstractPooledConnAdapter.open(AbstractPooledConnAdapter.java:121)
at org.apache.http.impl.client.DefaultRequestDirector.tryConnect(DefaultRequestDirector.java:561)
at org.apache.http.impl.client.DefaultRequestDirector.execute(DefaultRequestDirector.java:415)
at org.apache.http.impl.client.AbstractHttpClient.execute(AbstractHttpClient.java:820)
at org.apache.http.impl.client.AbstractHttpClient.execute(AbstractHttpClient.java:754)
at com.eviware.soapui.impl.wsdl.support.http.HttpClientSupport$Helper.execute(HttpClientSupport.java:233)
at com.eviware.soapui.impl.wsdl.support.http.HttpClientSupport.execute(HttpClientSupport.java:323)
at com.eviware.soapui.impl.wsdl.submit.transports.http.HttpClientRequestTransport.submitRequest(HttpClientRequestTransport.java:290)
at com.eviware.soapui.impl.wsdl.submit.transports.http.HttpClientRequestTransport.sendRequest(HttpClientRequestTransport.java:220)
at com.eviware.soapui.impl.wsdl.WsdlSubmit.run(WsdlSubmit.java:119)
at com.eviware.soapui.impl.wsdl.WsdlSubmit.submitRequest(WsdlSubmit.java:79)
at com.eviware.soapui.impl.wsdl.WsdlRequest.submit(WsdlRequest.java:217)
at com.eviware.soapui.impl.wsdl.teststeps.WsdlTestRequestStep.run(WsdlTestRequestStep.java:364)
at com.eviware.soapui.impl.wsdl.support.AbstractTestCaseRunner.runTestStep(AbstractTestCaseRunner.java:211)
at com.eviware.soapui.impl.wsdl.testcase.WsdlTestCaseRunner.runCurrentTestStep(WsdlTestCaseRunner.java:47)
at com.eviware.soapui.impl.wsdl.support.AbstractTestCaseRunner.internalRun(AbstractTestCaseRunner.java:138)
at com.eviware.soapui.impl.wsdl.support.AbstractTestCaseRunner.internalRun(AbstractTestCaseRunner.java:46)
at com.eviware.soapui.impl.wsdl.support.AbstractTestRunner.run(AbstractTestRunner.java:129)
at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Unknown Source)
at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(Unknown Source)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
    Caused by: java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused: connect
at java.net.DualStackPlainSocketImpl.connect0(Native Method)
at java.net.DualStackPlainSocketImpl.socketConnect(Unknown Source)
at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.doConnect(Unknown Source)
at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connectToAddress(Unknown Source)
at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connect(Unknown Source)
at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.connect(Unknown Source)
at java.net.SocksSocketImpl.connect(Unknown Source)
at java.net.Socket.connect(Unknown Source)
at org.apache.http.conn.scheme.PlainSocketFactory.connectSocket(PlainSocketFactory.java:123)
at com.eviware.soapui.impl.wsdl.support.http.SoapUIMultiThreadedHttpConnectionManager$SoapUIClientConnectionOperator.openConnection(SoapUIMultiThreadedHttpConnectionManager.java:262)
```

I am sure that I set Proxy to :None in `file > Preferences >Proxy settings`.

Also I turned off the Windows Firewall.
I also tried another tool `Storm` to test the web service. And I got another error:

```
System.Reflection.TargetInvocationException: Exception has been thrown by the target of an invocation. ---> System.Net.WebException: Unable to connect to the remote server ---> System.Net.Sockets.SocketException: No connection could be made because the target machine actively refused it xxx.xxx.x.xxx:80
at System.Net.Sockets.Socket.DoConnect(EndPoint endPointSnapshot, SocketAddress socketAddress)
at System.Net.ServicePoint.ConnectSocketInternal(Boolean connectFailure, Socket s4, Socket s6, Socket& socket, IPAddress& address, ConnectSocketState state, IAsyncResult asyncResult, Int32 timeout, Exception& exception)
 --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
 at System.Web.Services.Protocols.WebClientProtocol.GetWebResponse(WebRequest request)
 at System.Web.Services.Protocols.HttpWebClientProtocol.GetWebResponse(WebRequest request)
 at System.Web.Services.Protocols.SoapHttpClientProtocol.Invoke(String methodName, Object[] parameters)
 at DirectLinkTrustV0102.ValidateCaller(ValidateCallerInput input)
 --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
 at System.RuntimeMethodHandle._InvokeMethodFast(Object target, Object[] arguments, SignatureStruct& sig, MethodAttributes methodAttributes, RuntimeTypeHandle typeOwner)
 at System.Reflection.RuntimeMethodInfo.Invoke(Object obj, BindingFlags invokeAttr, Binder binder, Object[] parameters, CultureInfo culture, Boolean skipVisibilityChecks)
 at System.Reflection.RuntimeMethodInfo.Invoke(Object obj, BindingFlags invokeAttr, Binder binder, Object[] parameters, CultureInfo culture)
 at Storm.UI.Forms.FormMainOps.clo@651.Invoke(Object[] methodParams@41)
 at <StartupCode$Storm>.$Type.bgworker.run@51@57_2.Invoke(DoWorkEventArgs dArgs)
 at <StartupCode$Storm>.$Type.bgworker.run@51@57_1.Invoke(Object sender, DoWorkEventArgs e)
 at System.ComponentModel.BackgroundWorker.WorkerThreadStart(Object argument)
```

BTW, I can open it from the browser.
Thanks for help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally I figured it out. When you add the uri to SoapUI, even it has the https format. The SoapUI still use http as default in the request. You may might overlook it.

You have to manually to edit the endpoint in the address bar of `Request1`.

Answer (score 1):

You tell that to invoke the server use of https is required, however it seems that you're using http instead since the error message from soapui is:
`ERROR:org.apache.http.conn.HttpHostConnectException: Connection to http://xxxxx.com`

And from Storm:
`System.Net.Sockets.SocketException: No connection could be made because the target machine actively refused it xxx.xxx.x.xxx:80`

So check that you're really using the https (default port is 443) in your soapui request, because probably the server is refusing the connection in port 80 since it's listenting in 443.

Hope it helps,

Comment: I don't know why the use of https resulted in http. I have no control of the remote server. Should I contact the third party? And how to change the port to 443?

Comment: 443 is the default port for https, make sure that you're really invoking https as endpoint in your soapui request. In case that you're really using it maybe there is a problem in the third party which redirects your call from 443 to 80... or since you say that you can connect using browser maybe GET is allowed but not POST... unfortunately there are many possible explanations for this error `:(`